# Opening a new question after significantly editing another on hold

Tags: discussion, edits, on-hold, reposts

When is it appropriate to create a new question from a previous one on hold? I had a submission that required several edits to clarify. It was finally placed on hold. I posted another question that totally changed the references, the relevant statements and even altered the title but the new post was instantly deleted and I was told I must instead apply the new edits to the original post even though they read completely different and the focus is changed. I just need to know to avoid future mistakes with significant edits.

Answer (score 6):

If you're asking the same question in a clearer/better way, then edit the question.

If you no longer have that question, and instead want to ask a completely different question, then you ask a new question.

Comment: Are you suggesting go with the moderators suggestion? I will in the future but I also know my specialty very well and doubt he understood the nuances of the change. But if the rules are to reopen a question on hold even after major edits I shall comply

Comment: @RichardStanzak I couldn't speak to the specifics of your question without seeing it.  You've given me no reason to doubt the moderators decision.  You haven't said anything that indicates you have a different question, rather than a need to improve your existing question.

Comment: My concern was because the totally revised question was instantly deleted, too soon to have been read. I am okay with this as long as the rules are questions even remotely related to those on hold must first resolve the first submission

Answer (score 2):

If you believe it's a new question, you can ask separately, but treat it like a duplicate flag: *explain* clearly the *ways* in which the new question differs from the old one (but without tedious meta-commentary about how important it is that close-voters get it right).

Otherwise, [editing the original is best](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234378/is-it-accepable-to-repeat-ask-a-question/234379#234379). Editing is the designed way to leave the most history around cleanly. You can sometimes delete the original and re-ask, but it has to be clear that you're not just trying to slyly evade the decisions of the close- and reopen-voters on your original question.

Comment: As a new user I had no idea about the voting process to delete versus on hold. I now  suspect the moderators believed I was trying to do a workaround on them when I deleted the initial question then posted the significantly edited version. Thank you for taking the time to explain this to me